# I'm getting an error when I tired to load csv in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have imported the mmlspark to use LightGBM, if I do not do this, any thing is well.

```
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp") \
        .config("spark.jars.packages", "com.microsoft.ml.spark:mmlspark_2.11:1.0.0-rc3") \
        .config("spark.jars.repositories", "https://mmlspark.azureedge.net/maven") \
        .getOrCreate()
train_df = spark.read.csv('/content/drive/My Drive/BDCproj/train.csv', header=True, inferSchema=True)
test_df = spark.read.csv('/content/drive/My Drive/BDCproj/test.csv', header=True, inferSchema=True)
```

then my error:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-ba0da364400e> in <module>()
----> 1 train_df = spark.read.csv('/content/drive/My Drive/BDCproj/train.csv', header=True, inferSchema=True)
      2 test_df = spark.read.csv('/content/drive/My Drive/BDCproj/test.csv', header=True, inferSchema=True)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o214.csv.
: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroFileFormat could not be instantiated
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:803)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:721)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1394)
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:44)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:255)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.filterImpl$(TraversableLike.scala:249)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filterImpl(Traversable.scala:108)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.filter(TraversableLike.scala:347)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.filter$(TraversableLike.scala:347)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:649)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSourceV2(DataSource.scala:733)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:723)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor16.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/FileFormat$class
    at org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroFileFormat.<init>(AvroFileFormat.scala:44)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:779)
    ... 29 more
```

My spark is 3.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Try with this syntax once. If it helps do give it a green check.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp").config("spark.jars.packages","com.microsoft.ml.spark:mmlspark_2.11:1.0.0-rc3").config("spark.jars.repositories", "https://mmlspark.azureedge.net/maven").getOrCreate()



train = spark.read.option("header",True).csv("/complete/path/to/train.csv")
test = spark.read.option("header",True).csv("/complete/path/to/test.csv")
```

Hope this works!

Comment: thx, but it does not work. I just found that only spark2 works well.

Comment: @yangzeng the code i sent has been written using spark 3.0 Sorry, I should have mentioned the version